# 403/Forbidden using delphi application to access my Google calendar

Tags: delphi, google-calendar-api, indy10

Can anyone tell me why i'm having trouble accessing my calendar information?  I'm getting 403 forbidden.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  stringStream: TStringStream;
  slPost, slReply: TStringList;
  sPostResult: string;
begin
  slPost := TStringList.Create;
  slReply := TStringList.Create;
  try
    slPost.LineBreak := '&';
    slPost.Values['Email'] := 'me@gmail.com';
    slPost.Values['Passwd'] := 'pass';
    slPost.Values['service'] := 'cl';
    slPost.Values['source'] := 'company-program-version';

    stringStream := TStringStream.Create(slPost.Text);
    try
      IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
      sPostResult := IdHTTP1.Post('https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin', stringStream);

      slReply.LineBreak:=#10;
      slReply.Text:=sPostResult;
      slReply.LineBreak:=#13#10;
      Memo1.Lines.Add(slReply.Text);
      Memo1.Lines.Add('response=' + IdHTTP1.ResponseText);

// 200 OK
      sPostResult := IdHTTP1.Post('https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin', stringStream);

      IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.FoldLines:=false;
      IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Clear;
      IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['GData-Version']:='2.0';
      IdHTTP1.Request.CustomHeaders.Values['Authorization']:='GoogleLogin auth=' + slReply.Values['auth'];

(* custom headers:
      GData-Version: 2.0
      Authorization: GoogleLogin (line continues) auth=DQwhateverwhateverwhateverwhateverwhateverwhateverwhateverwhateverwhateverwhateverwhateverwhateverwhateverwhateverwhateverwhateverwhateverwhateverwhateverwhateverwhateverwhatever *)

      IdHTTP1.Request.ContentType := 'application/atom+xml';

// 403 Forbidden
      memo1.Lines.Add(IdHTTP1.Get('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/users/me/calendarList'));
    finally
      stringStream.Free;
    end;
  finally
    slPost.Free;
    slReply.Free;
  end;
end;
```

thank you!
mp

Comment: Do you have the SSL libraries installed and setup for use by Indy?

Answer (score 1):

After some reading, I think you need to deal with Redirect. So If response is redirect, get the new url, reattach the authorization to the new request header with the new url. Otherwise your redirection request will be missing the required authorization and give you 403 error.

Comment: You seem to be on the right track. Google does always redirect after login (watch your browser when logging in). Indy can handle the redirects for you, it does have a property to instruct it to do so, but the name escapes me at the moment.

Comment: You are thinking of the `TIdHTTP.HandleRedirects` property. There is also a `TIdHTTP.OnRedirect` event.

Comment: Thank you.  HandleRedirects=true but OnRedirect never fires.  I'm stuck.

Comment: @xray, do you use traffic monitor s/w? If not you can use wireshark, for example. You can capture the http/https traffics. Start capture on wireshark, and run your program. You will see the traffics on capture screen. On the capture screen, you can right click on the first request and choose 'follow tcp stream' and you can see the full conversation (request/response). For example, you can see if the server REALLY redirects the request, and see what authentication methods the server supports. At least it gives you more clues on whats going on.